# How to horizontally inline the logo and social media

Tags: css, inline

i have my logo and social media on top of the nav menu, my problem is when i reach the 480x320px, the social media goes down below the logo. logo and social media must be on the same line(top).

```
here's my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/craybac/x5rberhu/
```

here's the image:

[image]

=====================================================================================
I followed the format of Pawel but some problems exist. kindly see.

at 1024x768, 768x1024, 480x320 the social media went on top of the page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

then at 320x480, here's what happen.

[image]

i already adjusted the width of the logo and social media when it reaches to 800x600 up to 480x320, this case i resolved.

Comment: all images are broken in the JsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change order, and move

```
<div class="SOCIAL-MEDIA">...</div>
```

before

```
        <a href="index.html" class="egt-logo-link">     
            <img class="image-responsive" src="images/egtdesign-logo.png">
        </a>
```

if it will be still under log, adjust margins
http://jsfiddle.net/x5rberhu/8/

Comment: Pawel, thanks for the help it changed a little but there are still problem, the social media went on top of the page and when i reached at 320x480 it reversed the problem. see new uploaded image.

Comment: i think it is caused by: 
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
try to change location of this element on page, is it before <div class="SOCIAL-MEDIA">...</div>?

Comment: @powel, toggle navigation is after social media.

Comment: provide more html. You could try to wrap : <div class="SOCIAL-MEDIA">...</div>  and <a href="index.html" class="egt-logo-link">     
            <img class="image-responsive" src="images/egtdesign-logo.png">
        </a>
in div.